# Authorization denied for bot when attempting to create conversation via API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to develop a bot to be used exclusively for proactive messaging (since unfortunately, it appears Connectors do not support direct messaging). I stood up a web service, and was able to receive the payload from Teams when I sent a message to the bot.

I'm now trying to send a proactive message from the bot back to my user, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-send-and-receive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#start-a-conversation). Per the instructions, I am POSTing the following payload to `<serviceUrl>/v3/conversations`. (Values in brackets are interpolated from the payload I received from Teams)

```
{
    "bot": {
        "id": <recipient.id>,
        "name": <recipient.name>
    },
    "isGroup": false,
    "members": [
        {
            "id": <from.id>,
            "name": <from.name>
        }
    ],
    "tenantId": <channelData.tenant.id>,
    "topicName": "News Alert"
}
```

I also included a Bearer token that I got by calling `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<channelData.tenant.id>/oauth2/v2.0/token`. Yet, whenever I try to create the conversation, it fails with an error that "Authorization has been denied for this request." As far as I can tell, the token should be valid, so I'm not sure what else could be going on here. I saw something about trusting the service URL, but I'm not sure how I would do that since I'm not using the Bot SDK. Perhaps I'm going about this wrong and should be trying to create an Activity rather than a Conversation?

Comment: Outside of your application, can you repro the issue with above same API call/payload using Microsoft Graph Explorer or POSTMAN as well?

Comment: Share the requestid/timestamp of the detailed error that you got.

Comment: Can you confirm if the user has actually installed the bot application (I presume side-loaded via App Studio or similar)? You've probably side-loaded it to your own account?

Comment: @Dev I've been doing all of this in Postman already. There are no details to the error beyond the "authorization has been denied" message I included in the OP.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow Yes, I have sideloaded via App Studio. The payload I have is from a message sent to the bot, so I'm assuming it's properly installed, but if there are other things I could debug, I can check those out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured out the problem. I sent my token request to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<channelData.tenant.id>/oauth2/v2.0/token`, which was successful and gave me a token back. However, the instructions outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) say not to use `<channelData.tenant.id>`, but instead just the hardcoded string `botframework.com`. After requesting the token that way, my requests appear to be working.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two steps in sending pro-active messages. The first step is just a once-off - it's getting the unique ID of the conversation between the bot and the user. It's the paragraph you're linking to in your original question, and it's the payload sample you're showing. Once you've got that conversation id, you'd then proceed to sending messages at any time in the future (that's [this paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-send-and-receive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#send-message)).

However, in Teams, the first part is handled differently. Rather than calling the bot framework conversation endpoint (recall that bot framework is used for other things aside from Teams bots), you wait for the user to install the app, which includes your bot. When this is done, your bot will receive a [conversationUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications#team-member-or-bot-addition) event. When this fires, you'll be sent a payload which includes the conversationId of the newly-created conversation. This replaces the call you're currently making.

You need to save the conversationId, and the serviceUrl (which will be similar too 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis', but unique for Teams, and will be the 'base' of the URL you'll call later).

Importantly, it is possible to "pre-install" an app for a user, using the Graph API. See [Install app for user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-post-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

That should help with what you're missing. However, as an 'fyi', you can use libraries for this instead of making the call directly yourself. In dotnet, for instance, you can reference `Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConnectorClient` (in `Microsoft.Bot.Connector`), which has a `Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(..)` method.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply! I guess my first question would be why I can't proactively create the conversation instead of using an existing one. But second, even trying the approach of replying to the existing conversation (following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), I get the same authorization error.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that you can "pre-install" the app, so to speak, using Microsoft Graph - answer updated

Comment: If you're still having auth issues after that, it sounds like there's an issue with your app password. Probably your config for you app is wrong. What platform are you using (dotnet/node/etc.) and what sample / wizard / tool did you start with to build your bot?

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. I was interpolating the `tenantId` instead of `botframework.com` in the URL of the token request. That still gave me a token back, but  that token wasn't valid for the requests I was making.